# problem with factorial equations!

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

this is my first post here

I'm studying for an exam and have problems with simplifying math problems including factorials.

Here is an example 1:
$$
\frac{(n-3)!}{132} =10!  \implies n=\ ?
$$
apparently the answer is $15$ but i dunno the way?

another example 2:
$$
\frac{(a-3)!}{x!} = 120  \implies \min(a+x)=\ ? 
$$
(answer is $8$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try using mathjax to make your question more presentable.

Comment: hi. thnax for your welcome and also i don't know what mathjax is and how to use it really 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $132=11\times12$. So\begin{align}\frac{(n-3)!}{132}=10!&\iff(n-3)!=12\times11\times10!=12!\\&\iff n-3=12\\&\iff n=15.\end{align}Can you do the other one?

Comment: wow! thak you so soo much. it looks so easy when u explained it! and i feel stupid for not being able to solve the other one! except for the part i could find 120=5!  

Comment: i got it! thank you so much again!